# See the updated document in allow / deny rule in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'd like to specify an allow rule for document update in Meteor.js that would depend on the properties of the **updated** document. In the [`update`](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) callback, all I get is the **old** document, list of changed top-level fields and a Mongo modifier. Is there an easy way to determine how the document would look like if it was updated?

---

A non-trivial real-life example: I've got a `Party` model with `maxCount` integer that specifies how many people can fit in the party, and `people` array with names of people attending. A user can push several names to that array. I'd like to allow the update to be made if in the resulting document the length of the array would not exceed `maxCount`.

Comment: this needs to happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why allow/deny rules in their current form are insufficient for most real world problems. There are a multitude of ways any document can be updated, and it's impractical to check all of them with the tools that allow/deny gives you. I'd say you should use them only if you permissions look like: "the owner of a document can do whatever she wants with the document".

That being said, if you **really** want to do this with the example above you could try checking if `people.length < maxCount` when `modifier['$push']['people']` is defined.

As far as I know, a general solution to this problem does not exist. This is why I use methods for all db mutations.

You can also have a look at [simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/) and [collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) (I haven't tried them). According to the docs, simple-schema can take a function when defining a `min/max` on a field. I'm unclear if that means you can dynamically define the `min/max` based on the object being updated or not.

Comment: How would you do this in the method then?  Since allow / deny also run on the server I don't think there are any limitations about the data access or functions they can call.  So why is it easier test the modifier against the existing data there than in the allow / deny?

Comment: For the example above you could define a method like `partyAddPerson` which takes a `userId` and a `partyId`. Prior to any modifications, the current state of the party will be examined. The objective of such a function is clearly defined. Contrast this to an allow directive which could have an arbitrarily complex `modifier`. I find it easier to reason about a small set of whitelisted operations instead of attempting to blacklist against an unknown set.

Answer (score 0):

I am not the meteor expert here, but there seems to be a basic way of "enforcing" this constraint.

For most MongoDB informed people, the most "atomic" method of *incrementing* a value is to use the `$inc` operator in an `.update()` statement. That way you **ensure** that when the value is "updated", then the "present" value will be "incremented" by the set value, and at the time of the update.

The problem here clearly lies with enforcing a "maximum" constraint. So let's say `30` people. Pretty sad party I know:

```js
db.party.update(
    { "maxCount": { "$lt": 30 } },
    { "$inc": { "maxCount": 1 } }
})
```

So that should work as a statement inside your "add person to party" method. You can check the returned values in the [callback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update) ( see "numberUpdated" ) to make sure that something was updated or whether it was not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this answer is a bit unrelated. What I want is to find the resulting state of an object in allow rule in Meteor.js. I've updated the question to avoid confusion.